# upgrade R 2.7.1 on Debian core procedure

Tags: r, debian, upgrade

My R version is 2.7.1 (on Debian) and some packages are asking for > 2.10. I cannot find updating instructions and I don't want to remove and reinstall as I have other things depending on R and I don't want to mess up. Is there an update procedure?

Closest thing to my problem is on [this thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-debian/2010-May/001199.html).

Comment: Does this speak to your question? http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README

Comment: @Roman Luštrik my mistake, is Debian not Ubuntu. I'll try this http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI

It seems that R on Debian with versions previous to 2.7.1 **cannot be updated**. 
The [current core](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/r-base) runs from 2.7.1 up. The only way to do it is to remove the existing version.

As this was not straight forward I post it here. If you have Rapache or other things connecting to R disable them with *dismode* or related.

```
apt-get purge r-base r-base-dev
```

I had to do this as well

```
dpkg -P r-base-core
```

until this shows no more installed R packages

```
dpkg -l r-*
```

Then follow the instruction from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian/, with the amendment that you should use deb instead of deb-src in /etc/apt/sources.list.

```
deb http://<favorite-cran-mirror>/bin/linux/debian lenny-cran/
```

Before installing run this and it should not say 2.7.1.

```
apt-cache policy r-base-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the instructions for installing from source. Its easy on a Linux box, and you can  do the install in any directory you like, you dont even need superuser permissions. Once compiled you can even run R from that directory without messing up any system-installed R. As long as you give the full path to R's binary, or put the path to it in your PATH environment variable, when starting it it will work fine.

Comment: I just said that I don't want to install it

Comment: You said you wanted an update. Sometimes its just easier to get a new version and install alongside the old version. Stuff that depends on the old version carries on working, and stuff that needs the new version can be told to use it. Everybody wins.

Comment: Things like Rapache that depend on paths will not work, that is why I want an update not a parallel install.

Comment: I always find that when you start getting very specific version requirements and have a lot of sub-systems that depend on them it's easier to install from source rather than rely on a package system.

Comment: I had a very specific question, I don't want to enter in global/general discussions about the merits of packaging systems.

Comment: It was a vague question. You said you had 'other things depending on R'. Depending on the currently installed version of R? I wasn't taking R away from you at all. Just giving you options. Always a good thing.